# GraphQl typescript class to query/mutation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql

Is something like this possible where we create a graphql query out of a typescript class potentially using reflection?

```
export class GraphQlMagicGenerator {

    fetch(query: string, args: any) {

    }
}
export class PatientsQuery extends GraphQlMagicGenerator {
    constructor(patientId: number) {
        super()

        super.fetch("patient", {
            id: patientId
        })
    }

id:()=> number
name:()=> string
age:()=> number
}

// ^ behind the scenes generates a query for patient with an id argument and fills in id, name and age
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. because

1. Every query needs to develop a class to match it. class will affect the size of the target code.
2. GraphQL is highly flexible and dynamic, its query parameters determine which fields need to be queried. Even for the same query, different parameters will lead to different return types. It will be particularly tiring if you try to manually define the return type for every query like this.
3. The data types corresponding to different queries contain some of the same information, there will be a lot of redundancy in the code.

I suggest my framework, it brings the magical development experience for GraphQL Client.

https://github.com/babyfish-ct/graphql-ts-client

1. A code generator is supported to download the schema information from server and generate client TypeScript files. It won't generate "class" for functionalities without logic so that the size of target code will not be affected.
2. It allows you to write strongly-typed GraphQL request, not only arguments, but also a strongly typed tree structure to describe which fields should be queried.
3. Be different with other similar frameworks, it does not require user to define all possible queries in advance, for each specific query, **it can infer the type of returned data according to the strongly type request**.

like this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should be doing the opposite: defining your schema in `.graphql` and then codegening your TypeScript types from there. I am using [gql2ts](https://github.com/amount/gql2ts) (though there are others.) Then just create a script as part of your build phase.

You can customize the codegen'd portion to fit your team's particular style as well. For example, I've removed namespacing, overriden `enum` generation, and marked the generated types all as `readonly`. But your schema *is* your API and so it should define your types.

Comment: my workflow is already better than that and doesn't require defining a schema then a separate resolver, they're both one - using https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql

Now I just want something that can turn a typescript class into a query which should be possible.

At this point writing out my own schema then converting it to typescript then writing the resolves for it is a step back )